# Как сделать автогенерацию значений не id поля jpa hibernate

Tags: база-данных, hibernate, jpa, entity, formula

Есть поле(не id) - number, для которого нужно настроить автогенерацию, и каждый следующий номер будет на 1 больше предыдущего(чтобы генерировался при persist'е). Через триггеры бд не надо, через дополнительный класс - только для генерации id - тоже, через @PrePersist @PreDestroy - тоже. Пробовал @GeneratedValue - не работает на простом поле. @Formula - не запускается(в логах смотрел, запрос не проходит, чтобы заполнить поле), выполнил то же в бд, все работает.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
public class Policeman implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

@Column
@Formula("select max(student_id) from student")
   private Long number;


    @Column
    private String fam;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String otch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучший вариант - прописать hibernate_sequence в скрипте базы.
В вашем варианте у вас есть строка @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) - но от чего именно отталкиваться, от какого числа, вы не написали

Попробуйте добавить следующее перед вашим полем:

```
public static final int START_SEQ = 100000;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "global_seq", sequenceName = "global_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = START_SEQ)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "global_seq")
```

Comment: Мне не нужно, чтобы поле было id. В этом то весь и смысл. Нужно обработать поле "number"

Comment: исключите аннотацию @Id и примените все остальное для поля Number

Comment: Снова null. Вот что в дебаге получаю  id = {Long@11457} "670"
result = {Policeman@9711} 
 number = null
 name = null
 fam = null
 otch = null

Comment: @SequenceGenerator(name = "global_seq", sequenceName = "global_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "global_seq")
    private Long number; //не работает

Comment: Добавляю через entityManager.persist(new Policeman());

Comment: у вас автогенерация таблицы, или свой скрипт?

Comment: Автогенерация. Я же прикрепил код своей entity

Comment: геттеры и сеттеры у вас есть в коде?

Comment: Конечно есть, просто не вижу смысла их выписывать, они стандартные, сгенерированные идеей